# Tkinter: Adding a scrollbar to a canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to my tkinter window which stays in place and scrolls through a frame. However, whenever I launch the application, the scrollbar is greyed out. Here is the relevant excerpt from my code:

```
    self.bigFrame = ttk.Frame(self,width = 1080,height = 500)
    self.hsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.bigFrame,orient = "horizontal")
    self.hsb.pack(side = TOP, fill = X)


    self.treeCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.bigFrame,width = 1080,height = 500,xscrollcommand = self.hsb.set)




    self.treeFrame = tk.Frame(self.treeCanvas,width = 1080,height = 500)




    self.treeCanvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.treeFrame,anchor = 'nw')
    self.treeCanvas.config(scrollregion  = self.treeCanvas.bbox("all"))
    self.treeCanvas.pack(side = BOTTOM,fill = X)
    self.treeFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM,fill = X)

    self.hsb.config(command = self.treeCanvas.xview)





    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.treeFrame,selectmode='browse',height = 100, columns = ('name','purchaseprice','previousprices','listingprice','buyingformat','postage','fees','potprofit','offers','viewcount','sold','offertaken','username','dispatch','delivered','returned','relist','feedback'))
    self.tree.heading('#0',text = 'saleID',anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('name',text = "Item Name",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('purchaseprice',text = "Purchase Price",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('previousprices',text = "Previous Prices",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('listingprice',text = "Listing Price", anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('buyingformat',text = "Buying Format",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('postage',text = "Postage",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('fees',text = "Fees",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('potprofit',text = "Potential Profit",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('offers',text = "Best Offer",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('viewcount',text = "Viewcount",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('sold',text = "Sold?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('offertaken',text = "Offer Taken?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('username',text = "Username",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('dispatch',text = "Dispatched?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('delivered',text = "Delivered?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('returned',text = "Returned?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('relist',text = "Relisted?",anchor = 'w')
    self.tree.heading('feedback',text = "Feedback",anchor = 'w')


    self.tree.pack(side = BOTTOM, fill = X)

    self.bigFrame.grid(row = 11,column = 0,columnspan = 100,pady=(5,0),sticky = 'nw')
    self.bigFrame.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight = 1)
    self.bigFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight = 1)
    self.bigFrame.grid_propagate(False)
```

I'm sure it's an issue with the ordering of lines, but none of the orders I've tried have worked.

Comment: Try setting the maximum value of the scrollbar to the width of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your scrollbar is greyed out is because you are missing this line:

```
self.treeFrame.update_idletasks()
```

Below implemented in the rest of your code.

```
...
self.treeCanvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.treeFrame,anchor = 'nw')

# add this
self.treeFrame.update_idletasks()
bbox = self.treeCanvas.bbox(tk.ALL)

# Update this
self.treeCanvas.config(scrollregion=bbox, width=DISPLAY_WIDTH, height=DISPLAY_HEIGHT)

self.treeCanvas.pack(side = BOTTOM,fill = X)
self.treeFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM,fill = X)
...
```

Hopefully this answer helps, if not you could try [the last answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731784/tkinter-canvas-scrollbar-with-grid), which helped me alot.