# How to make a functionnal scrollable canvas using tkinter, tkinter.tkk and python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build my first application using python, tkinter and tkinter.ttk and I, unfortunetaly, can't seem to find a way to efficiently scroll past a group of widgets by grouping them all in a canvas...

I've already gone through many forums and haven't really found an answer. I've tried everything I've found but in vain. This is the code I've managed to build so far :

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window = Tk()
window.configure(background = 'lightgray')


#creates the main canvas
canvas = Canvas(window, width=5000, height=3000, bg = "lightgray")


#creates the canvas scrollbar (hopefully)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window, orient= VERTICAL)
scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = W)
scrollbar.configure(command = canvas.yview, scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))

canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)


#those are the types of widgets I'd like to scroll through : 
for i in range(50):
    ask_name = Label(canvas, text = "What is your name : ")
    ask_name.grid(row = i, column = 0, sticky = W)

    field_file_name = Entry(canvas, width = 20)
    field_file_name.grid(row = i, column = 1, sticky = W)

    filler = Label(canvas, text= "\n")
    filler.grid(row = i, column = 2)


window.mainloop()
```

When I run this piece of code, the scrollbar does appear but it's greyed out and when I remove the "canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)" 
bit, the scrollbar isn't greyed out but its buttons don't seem to work.

Comment: There is already a well answered post [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731784/tkinter-canvas-scrollbar-with-grid). Did you try to follow the answers there step by step?

Comment: You can't scroll widgets added to a canvas with `grid` and `pack`.